# how to give download link to vimeo videos using php

Tags: php, download, vimeo

```
<?php echo $videoFirstArray['fileToUpload'];?></a>
```

This portion fetches the vimeo videos from DB,now under it i want a download button so that the users can download the vimeo videos.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the problem here?

Comment: `<?php echo "<a href='{$videoFirstArray['fileToUpload']}'> download video </a>?>`

Comment: This mens something like this:<a href="<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/37582150" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>">download</a> and how <ifrmae></frame> can go inside <a href=""></a>

Comment: That's the iFrame, not the download link. You will need to store the download link for this to work.

Comment: hi all,that's my question,how to to download videos from iframe.I"ve managed to download youtube videos,but how i'll to the same thing for vimeo videos

Comment: How to store the download link for vimeo videos so as to able to download the videos

Comment: hi,some how managed to get vimeo video id,with this id is it possible to download the videos

Answer (score 0):

You can get the download link for a single video by calling the following API

```
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/{video_id}
```

In responses, you can find `respose['download']['link']`